# can i format the HTML alert box into my colors and style with css?

Tags: html, css, alert

i want to show an alert when someone click on Paypal button and the alert should say **you will be directed to Paypal website** but the basic html alert ox is awful in style ,

is there a way to improve its styling ?

or i have to design a div and code its functionality too?

Answer (score 1):

No. However, you can create a DIV tag which will be positioned absolute to look like an alert box or use jQuery UI to easily create dialog boxes, here http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: hmm but div tag don't have the functionality like alert that until u press **Ok** button the next process wont start ....

Comment: @nida: jQuery lets you define code which is run right after the **Ok** button is pressed.